# MySQL query unable to read PHP variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post

I have a HTML form (Datadisplay.html) which uses the POST method to give (datadisplay.php) variables name and model, which are integrated into the SQL query ($sql). The problem is that php doesn't display any errors, but my query displays just blank, in the HTML.

I know for a fact the rest works since when I replace `$this->name` and `$this->model` for strings it does pull up the info. any help would be appreciated.

```
MYSQL TABLE AS
 id int(11)
 nombre varchar(100)
fecha_remision date
modelo varchar(100)
serial varchar(100)
numero_arraigo varchar(100)
```

DATA DISPLAY PHP

```
<?php
//ERROR_REPORTING( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
 if(isset($_POST['type'])){
class DataDisplay
{
//Variable for MySql connection
  private $hookup;
 private $sql;
    private $tableMaster;
private $name;
      private $model;


 public function __construct()
 {
    //Get table name and make connection

    $this->table=$_POST['type'];
    $this->hookup=UniversalConnect::doConnect();
    $this->doDisplay();
    $this->hookup->close(); 
    $this->name=$_POST['name'];
    $this->model=$_POST['model']; 
}

 private function doDisplay()
{
        //Create Query Statement
    $this->sql ="SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE modelo='$this->model' AND    

  nombre='$this->name'";

    try
    {
    $result = $this->hookup->query($this->sql);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
         echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>id " . $row['id'] . "</td></br>";
 echo "<td>Nombre " . $row['nombre'] . "</td></br>";
 echo "<td>fecha de remision " . $row['fecha_remision'] . "</td></br>";
 echo "<td>serial " . $row['serial'] . "</td></br>";
 echo "<td>modelo " . $row['modelo'] . "</td></br>";
 echo "<td>numero de arraigo " . $row['numero_arraigo'] . "</td></br>";
 echo "</tr></br>";


     }

    $result->close(); 
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
      echo "Here's what went wrong: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

 }
}
}
else
    {
    echo"<script>alert('selecciona tipo de activo');</script>";
    }
?>
```

data display html

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/easy.css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>SCAF</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <header>
 </header>
 <div>
 <h2>Consulta</h2>
 </div>
 <form action="Client.php" method="post" target="feedback">
 <div><strong>informacion del activo:</strong><br />
   <label for="name">Name:</label>
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
 <br />
 <!--cambiar modelo por proyecto(propiedad de tabla), tambien cambiar por radios de  
 nombre de proyectos-->
 <label for="model">modelo:</label>
 <input type="text" name="model" id="model">
 <br />
 <p />
 </div>
  <div><strong>categoria</strong><br />
<label for="cs2">transporte:</label>
<input type="radio" name="type" id="cs2" value="transporte">
<br/>
<label for="cs1">maquinaria:</label>
<input type="radio" name="type" id="cs1" value="maquinaria">
<br/>
<label for="cs">maquinaria pesada:</label>
<input type="radio" name="type" id="cs" value="maquinaria pesada">
<br />
 </div>
 <br />
   <div>
   <input type="submit" name="all" value="buscar">
  </div>
 </form>
 <p />
 <div><strong></strong>
  <p />
  </div>

  <iframe name="feedback" seamless width="300" height="200">PHP</iframe>
 <div>
 <p>
 <a href="EasyUpdateOOP.html">Update and Drop Files</a>
 </p>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: There's no need to shout, we can read you just fine!

Comment: sorry, just wanted to make things easier to read

Comment: Try do '". $this->model ."' instead of '$this->model'

Comment: `$this->sql ="SELECT * FROM ".$this->table." WHERE modelo='".$this->model."' AND nombre='".$this->name."'";`

Comment: well i had high hopes but no, one more note i forgot to add, the table name is read by mysql however the variables are not if i try to change just those variables for strings leaving $this->table  it does work

Comment: I've downvoted; if you wouldn't mind fixing the ALL UPPER CASE title, I'll undownvote.

Comment: i don`t think voting down would help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose object properties into curly braces if you want them parsed inside the double quotes:

```
$this->sql = 
   "SELECT * 
    FROM {$this->table} 
    WHERE modelo='{$this->model}' AND nombre='{$this->name}'";
```

Comment: if i do it like this it displays a query error on php, i'll try to make it work

Comment: What does the error say? Note that I had a typo in my answer until a minute ago (misplaced `'` and `}`).

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\SCAF1.0\DataDisplay.php on line 35 which is

Comment: while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())

Comment: var_dump the $result and see what it is... Also it might help to echo the query to make sure it's all good.

Comment: the query it's echoing SELECT * FROM this->table WHERE modelo='' AND nombre='', so it does give empty parameters to mysql, guess it might change if i use prepare
and var_dump gives boolean false

Comment: Then you forgot to put the curly braces (or the dollar sign) after FROM, and your variables/properties are missing.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\SCAF1.0\DataDisplay.php on line 23 it refuses to parse

Comment: Did you figure out what it was?

Comment: somewhat, so far i made it work for my first revision by using the variables as parameters, but im looking into changing the whole conection class to make it use prepare and see it that comes out better

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's kinda hard to tell what your issue is, but from what you've posted there are a couple of issues.  Here are things to look at:

1) i see you have defined a class based on the result of an 'if' clause.  In 10 years of programming i have never seen anyone do that, they usually just define the class and then use it later if needed.

2) i see that you are defining the class, but i don't see anywhere that you are actually instantiating an object of that class's type or calling any of the functions.  Try putting some simple: echo('hello') statements in various places to see if you are even getting to your code

3) as one of the other commenters stated, you cant put an object reference into double quotes.  ie you can not do this:

```
$whatever = "foo bar $this->derp whatnot";
```

you can instead do this:

```
$whatever = "foo bar " . $this->derp ." whatnot";
```

or (correct me if i'm wrong) i think you could also do it this way:

```
$whatever = "foo bar {$this->derp} whatnot";
```

Check your code for these types of errors and i think you'll find your problem

Comment: my bad for the if that was for testing purposes, and i'll try with the other 2 suggestions

Answer (score 0):

PHP string interpolation is covered well by the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple

Try the "complex" form of string interpolation:

```
// Works, quoted keys only work using the curly brace syntax
echo "This works: {$arr['key']} and produces the expected output.";
```

The alternative is to use concatenation:

```
echo "This works: " . $arr['key'] . " and produces the expected output.";
```

Do note that inserting values from a POST into a SQL query is a security hole of the first order because it allows SQL injection attacks. Please, for the safety of the Internet, use the PDO prepared statements system to do your substitutions into SQL statements, do NOT do it this way, you are giving a gateway for hackers into your server because the way you're doing it allows an attacker to insert arbitrary SQL subqueries that could do anything all the way up to deleting your database into your SQL query!

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: i'm sorry, im a novice to programming, i'm still a student, i do plan on making it right when i go over error handling, but right now i'm trying to make it work

Comment: I've seen many supposedly "professional" programmers write the simple PHP string substitution that you wrote. So if I sound annoyed, it's because I've had to clean up after these "professionals". Do investigate the PDO prepared statement system (and similar systems for other languages), it's the "right" way to do things.